# I'm using semantic ui react Card. I'm trying to create Memory game. is there a way i can have flip animation for the card.

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

My card Component

```
   <Card 
   image={card.flipped || card.discovered ? card.url : 'http://flotrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/placeholder-400x400.png'}
   onClick={() => flipCard(card.id)}
 />
```

There is a Reaveal component in library. like below.

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Image, Reveal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const RevealExampleFade = () => (
  <Reveal animated='fade'>
    <Reveal.Content visible>
      <Image src='/assets/images/wireframe/square-image.png' size='small' />
    </Reveal.Content>
    <Reveal.Content hidden>
      <Image src='/assets/images/avatar/large/ade.jpg' size='small' />
    </Reveal.Content>
  </Reveal>
)

export default RevealExampleFade
```

but it does animations on hover. Is there a way to make it switch content on click? I'm not able to see any examples where we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a Card become visible via the onClick event by conditionally rendering the Card component.  It will end up looking something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const FlipCard = (props) => {
  const { id, flipped, cardImage } = props.card
  const { hiddenImage, onCardFlip } = props

  if(flipped){
    //this image will be displayed once the card is clicked
    return(
      <Image width={200} src={cardImage} />
    )
  }
  else{
    //this image will be displayed if the card has not been clicked
    return(
      <Image id={id} onClick={onCardFlip} width={200} src={hiddenImage} />
    )
  }
}

class CardGame extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      cards : [
        {
          id: 0,
          flipped: false,
          cardImage: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Playing_card_spade_A.svg/2000px-Playing_card_spade_A.svg.png',
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          flipped: false,
          cardImage: 'http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/yugioh/images/d/d4/BlueEyesWhiteDragon-DUSA-EN-UR-1E.png/revision/latest?cb=20170330172041',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          flipped: false,
          cardImage: 'https://www.palossports.com/imagez/15327_12.jpg',
        },
      ],
      hiddenImage: 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/6c/a0/16/6ca016115a894f69dea75cc80f95ad92.jpg',
    }
  }

  handleCardFlip = (e, data) => {
    const cards = this.state.cards
    cards[e.target.id].flipped = true
    this.setState({ cards })
  }

  render(){
    const { hiddenImage, cards } = this.state

    const mappedCards = cards.map( card => {
      return(
        <FlipCard key={card.id} hiddenImage={hiddenImage} card={card} onCardFlip={this.handleCardFlip} />
      )
    })

    return(
      <div>
        { mappedCards }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CardGame
```

Comment: Hey, This is working. However there is an issue. card reveals on hover. Which i don't want. I want it to only reveal on click.

Comment: I misinterpreted what the active prop does.  The active prop on the Reveal component just makes it so it will reveal on hover.  
I believe that the issue with your problem is using the Reveal component in the first place as it doesn't seem to work in the manner you would like it to.  Instead of using Reveal, try using card+transition with an onClick event handler that will show/reveal the card upon being clicked.  I'll update my answer as soon as I get a bit of free time today to show how that might be possible.

Comment: Yes exactly, sure i will try that.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to better fit the solution I think you're looking for.